# Git ignoring obj files in Unity project

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore

I'm working on a unity project with git and i'm using a .gitignore file found on github.
I don't recognize which rule of the gitgnore file make this happen:
Git is ignoring the .obj files in "projectname/Assets/objs".

This is the .gitignore:

```
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore
#
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/[Ll]ogs/
/[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/

# MemoryCaptures can get excessive in size.
# They also could contain extremely sensitive data
/[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Asset meta data should only be ignored when the corresponding asset is also ignored
!/[Aa]ssets/**/*.meta

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
/[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.aab
*.unitypackage

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties

# Packed Addressables
/[Aa]ssets/[Aa]ddressable[Aa]ssets[Dd]ata/*/*.bin*

# Temporary auto-generated Android Assets
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa.meta
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa/*
```

The other question is: do I need to track these files? [files to track???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKNeO.jpg)

Comment: If those are compiler object files, you definitely don't want to track them.  `.obj` is usually an extension for compiler object files on Windows systems.

Comment: Why is it an issue its not tracking obj files as they are remade

Comment: Do you ignore them in your global gitignore?

Comment: @bk2204 In this context, the obj refers to a [Wavefront .obj file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) containing plaintext geometry data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to (and shouldn't) track `Library` folder. It's Unity's cached data which regenerates automatically if not present. Your `.gitignore` seems to exclude `Library` correctly, so it shouldn't be tracked - are you sure you placed the file exactly at the root of the project? It should be on the same level as folders such as `Assets` and `Library`.

To check if your `.gitignore` is responsible for not including something, use this:

```
git check-ignore -v -- some/path/to/check
```

It will output the responsible rule, if any.